# A Question about an Function of Integers

Tags: functional-equations, integers

Let $f$ denote a function. Given that $f(1)=1$, $f(2n)=2f(n)$, and $n\cdot f(2n+1)=(2n+1)\cdot(f(n)+n)$ where $n$ is a positive integer, the question is to prove that every $f(n)$ is an integer.
Though what needs to be proven is intuitively true, I am looking for some rigorous approach. Any idea or hint would be appreciated.

**Remark:** this problem has been solved thanks to lulu. Please see the two solutions posted below. Nevertheless, any new approach is always welcome.

Comment: Induction seems relevant.

Comment: Note:  I'm not sure how "intuitive" this is.  The fact that you require $nf(2n+1)=(2n+1)(f(n)+n)$ means that you have to prove that the right hand is an integer which is divisible by $n$.  That divisibility has to be part of your induction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Induction provides a fairly easy approach to the problem (note that your inductive hypothesis must be something like "$f(n)$ is an integer divisible by $n$").

Here, however, is a different approach:

Claim:  $f(n)$ is $n$ times the number of $1's$ in the base $2$ expansion of $n$.

Pf:  Let $F(n)$ be $n$ times the number of $1's$ in the base $2$ expansion of $n$, so we want to prove that $F(n)=f(n)$.  It is clear that $F(1)=f(1)=1$, so now assume that $n>1$.

Case I:  $n$ even.  So $n=2m$.  Let $k$ be the number of $1's$ in the base $2$ expansion of $m$, so that $F(m)=mk$.  Since $n=2m$ has the same binary expansion, with an extra $0$ we see that $F(2m)=2mk=2F(m)$ as desired.

Case II:  $n$ odd.  So $n=2m+1$.  Let $k$ be the number of $1's$ in the base $2$ expansion of $m$, so that $F(m)=mk$.  We note that $2m+1$ has exactly one more $1$ in its binary expansion than $m$ does so $F(2m+1)=(2m+1)(k+1)$.  It is then easy to confirm that $$mF(2m+1)=m(2m+1)(k+1)=(2m+1)(mk+m)=(2m+1)(F(m)+m)$$

Thus $F(n)$ satisfies the same recursion and initial condition as $f(n)$ so $F(n)=f(n)$ and we are done.

Comment: Hi, lulu. I am very excited to see this different approach of yours! Yet, could you kindly explain what "base 2 expansion" means? Thank you. @lulu

Comment: I  mean, write the integer in base $2$.  Thus, for example, $74_{10}=1001010_2$ so, using my notation, $F(74)=74\times 3$.

Comment: Note:  you should carry out the induction I indicated at the start.  That's certainly the easiest way to prove the desired claim, though I think the other approach carries more information.

Comment: I tried to write a solution by induction in the 'mundane' way but failed at the "proving true for $n=k+1$" step in which I considered $k$ being even or odd. It is midnight in my time region, and I can feel some brain block, so I am going to sleep for now. I will definitely delve into your ingenious approach tomorrow after I crack the 'mundane' approach. Thank you so much, lulu. @lulu

Comment: Lulu, I just checked out your ingenious approach. My jaw dropped for quite a while. It is so brilliant! I bet that the question was set on exactly the same thought which was hidden later by not giving the base 2 perspective. By the way, I have not solved this problem by the 'mundane' induction way; shame on me, and I will try again. Thank you again, lulu! @lulu

Comment: Hi, lulu. I just figured out the induction approach and I posted it below. If you do not mind, please kindly have a quick check on that since I am not very confident with my understanding on induction. Thanks a lot. @lulu

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a lot of thanks for lulu's induction hint and another non-inductive ingenious approach. Below is a proof by strong induction for future reference.

- Statement $S$: $f(n)$ is an integer divisible by $n$.
- Base step: $f(1)=1$ is divisible by $1$, so $S$ is true for $n=1$.
- Assumption step: assume $S$ is true for $n=1,2,...,k$ where $k$ is any positive integer.
- Inductive step: if $k$ is even, then $f(k+1)=(k+1)\cdot\left(\frac {f\left(\frac k2\right)}{\frac k2}+1\right)$. By assumption, since $\frac k2\lt k$, $\frac {f\left(\frac k2\right)}{\frac k2}$ is an integer, and then it is easy to deduce that $f(k+1)$ is an integer divisible by $k+1$. If $k$ is odd, then $f(k+1)=2f\left(\frac {k+1}{2}\right) \Rightarrow \frac {f(k+1)}{k+1}=\frac {f\left(\frac {k+1}{2}\right)}{\frac {k+1}{2}}$. By assumption, since $\frac {k+1}{2}\le k \Leftarrow k\ge1$, $f\left(\frac {k+1}{2}\right)$ is an integer divisible by $\frac {k+1}{2}$, and then $\frac {f(k+1)}{k+1}$ is an integer,  and then $f(k+1)$ is an integer divisible by $k+1$.
- Conclusion step: since $S$ is true for $n=1$, and $S$ is true for $n=k+1$ if true for $n=1,2,...,k$ where $k$ is any positive integer, by induction $S$ is true for any positive integer $n$.

Please kindly correct me if there is any mistake in the proof above. Thanks.

Comment: In your "Inductive Step", when $k$ is even we have $k+1$ odd so $k+1=2m+1$.  Then what you get is $m\times f(k+1)=(k+1)(f(m)+m)$.  In what you wrote, you omitted that initial factor of $m$ on the left.  You need to keep the factor of $(k+1)$ on the right, so you need to argue that $m$ divides $(f(m)+m)$.  Of course that follows from the Induction hypothesis since we have $m\,|\,f(m)$.